# How to check if controller response has link?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

What's a decent way of doing it? Preferably matching a regexp.

my current code is like this:

```
describe "get #show" do
  context "signed in" do
    it "should have a link to edit profile" do
      # i sign in the user
      get :show
      response # i don't know what to do here
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to do an [acceptance test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing), which probably means you should defer to [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). Then you can do magic like

`page.should have_css('edit_link', text: 'Edit me')`